# Get thumb filepath by image path

Tags: android

I am writing chat client and need to show images. I know filename (filepath) of big image, and want to get thumbnail path, in order to load into the chat feed.

An hour googling gave nothing - all methods return null for me..
It would be great if someone could provide some method like String      `getThumbPath(Context c, String filename)`
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple concise methods that have worked for me. Watch for null returns though. In that case, usually the image is small enough to use itself and create a scaled bitmap.

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                         getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri,
                         MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND,
                         (BitmapFactory.Options) null );
```

or

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(pictureFile.getPath());
byte[] imageData=exif.getThumbnail();
Bitmap  thumbnail= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData,0,imageData.length);
```

Comment: I have seen such an answeir. But still no idea how do get image path filename from it. I do not need bitmap, I am using android Universal Image loader, and it needs filename

Comment: I believe a thumbnail is part of its parent file's metadata and not its own separate file. You could get the thumbnail and write it to a new file, but that may not be the best strategy.